# MySQL Workbench 8.0.12 error: cannot satisfy dependencies

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install [MySQL Workbench 8.0.12](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads) in my Kubuntu 18.04. But I get this error:

> Cannot satisfy dependencies

[image]

What dependencies should I install? Any ideas?

Comment: Which command did you use? `dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb` ? It should have more informations than a simple "Cannot satisfy dependencies".

Comment: Did you tried?
    
    apt -f install

Comment: @MrShunz what is the full url for getting `mysql-workbench-community_8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb`?

Comment: VTC unclear until a meaningful error message is provided.

Comment: @laukok I just found it clicking on the link you provided...

Comment: @MrShunz that is where I downloaded the deb.

Comment: @laukok yes, that's the `.deb` I'm talking about. So you have it donwloaded, open a terminal, `cd` to _where_ you downloaded it and do a `dpkg -i mysql-workbench*.deb`, and post the errors you get.

Comment: @MrShunz fixed the error. see my answer below. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what dependencies it needs from the terminal:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /home/lau/Downloads/mysql-workbench-community_8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for lau: 
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community.
(Reading database ... 313027 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-workbench-community_8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libvsqlitepp3v5 (>= 0.3.13); however:
  Package libvsqlitepp3v5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community
```

So I downloaded **libvsqlitepp3v5** from [here](https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-amd64/libvsqlitepp3v5_0.3.13-4_amd64.deb.html). Installed it and then run `mysql-workbench-community_8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb` again.

No more error.